# Unable to install plotly in r studio

Tags: r, plotly

When I run plotly in my r studio, I got the following error

```r
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/data.table’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/75/kpj4ysfd0cx4qyv5cgyhn3sw0000gn/T/RtmpZHPWIC/downloaded_packages’
> library(plotly)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plotly’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘data.table’
```

After run the Command Sessioninfo() in R studio terminal, I got the following result:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tibble_2.1.3  readr_1.3.1   tidyr_0.8.3   purrr_0.3.2   ggplot2_3.2.1 dplyr_0.8.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5  xfun_0.8          remotes_2.1.0     colorspace_1.4-1  vctrs_0.2.0       testthat_2.2.1    htmltools_0.4.0   usethis_1.5.1     yaml_2.2.0       
[10] rlang_0.4.0       pkgbuild_1.0.6    pillar_1.4.2      glue_1.3.1        withr_2.1.2       sessioninfo_1.1.1 munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      devtools_2.2.1   
[19] memoise_1.1.0     labeling_0.3      knitr_1.24        callr_3.3.1       ps_1.3.0          curl_4.0          Rcpp_1.0.2        backports_1.1.4   scales_1.0.0     
[28] desc_1.2.0        pkgload_1.0.2     fs_1.3.1          hms_0.5.1         digest_0.6.20     processx_3.4.1    grid_3.6.1        rprojroot_1.3-2   cli_1.1.0        
[37] tools_3.6.1       magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.2    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.2   zeallot_0.1.0     ellipsis_0.3.0    prettyunits_1.0.2 assertthat_0.2.1 
[46] rstudioapi_0.10   R6_2.4.0          compiler_3.6.1
```

After the `clang -v` command:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Does anyone know what happens? Since `library(plotly)` is not working right now

Comment: Can you add the results of `clang -v` (run from terminal) and `sessionInfo()` (run from `R`) to your post?

Comment: Sure @SamuelDiebolt

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the installation of `data.table`, a package needed by `plotly`. The `-fopenmp` option used for compilation isn't supported on all platforms. I assume you're using macOS, and this option is [known to cause errors with Apple LLVM 9 and later](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2406).

I think installing an OpenMP enabled compiler should solve your problem. See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) to install `data.table` with an OpenMP enabled `clang` (section *OpenMP enabled compiler for Mac*).

Once you have `data.table` properly installed, running `install.packages("plotly")` should work.

Comment: @Rieder: Yes, you're indeed on macOS, so you need to follow the link I provided to install `data.table` using an OpenMP enabled compiler (in your case, `clang`). Feel free to ask if you run into problems when following the instructions. :-)

Comment: @Rieder Any news? Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark if it worked!